# Blank Admin page / unable to save any settings

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having an extremely frustrating issue occuring in my theme.  I was doing some dev work on my theme and suddenly, I started experienceing an issue where I was unable to save any changes made in the wordpress customizer.

I restarted thinking it was my browser, I tried to log back in and .../wp-admin  was blank, .../wp-login got me a 404 error.  Going to my URL the site was sitll live without any issues with the changes I tried to push through live and working.  If I keep a second browser window open and make changes to the customizer they occur but it says it can't save.

I tried the following:

1. renamed plugins folder - didnt work
2. back out of all the code i added in my dev session (to my knowldegde)
3. Only thing that made my admin page and login page work was changing my theme.

This is the frustrating thing about it, I cannot figure out what is causing these errors, chrome dev console is giving no unusual errors, the php error log is giving me nothing I havent already seen prior.

This is my last ditch effort to save a months worth of work  I dont know what to do, I have not been searching for a solution for 8 hours with 0 progress.

How could I find out what is causing this bug?

Please help

Comment: enable WP_DEBUG true in wp-config.php

Comment: already did, no fatal errors

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You said you think you removed all of your recent changes, but you must have missed something. Do you have any other backup versions of the theme, even fairly old ones? If so, you could try adding in parts, piece by piece, until you find the problematic code.

Comment: i have one on my work computer, I am going to try this.  Could this be a corrupted database issue?  could any code I added to my templates in my theme have caused this?

Comment: i fixed it, it was a space before the opening <?php tags in one of the templates files i was working on today when I was clicking around randomly I must have added it in and not noticed.  How infuriating

Comment: Wow, crazy. Well, I'm glad you were able to find it!